# How to generate gii crud Yii2 without Primary Key?

Tags: database, yii2, crud, gii

How can i generate the crud wihtout primary key because, my dabatase, this table don't have a primary key. there is FK only.
when i try to generate it will be like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtP1v.png).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: uhm... CRUD without Primary Key? and how do you do Update, Create or Dele without PK?

Comment: there is an enhancement pending which includes asking of the primary key in case there isnt any currently while generating the model which would be useful for `views` too, see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8277) but you need to have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it is not very good to use CRUD without PK. But, if there are no other options, you can add fake PK variable to table  temporarily and after generation delete that. You should change some code to escape errors on generated files (controller and views) to remove references to that fake variable. And you should be more careful, because, you could update or delete some other record instead needed one

**Update**

Assuming that the DB structure is like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU6Y8.jpg) and you should generate CRUD for the table '***othertable***', you can:

1. add PK as "id" to the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAzxB.jpg)
2. regenerate model "**Othertable**"
3. generate CRUD for "***othertable***"
4. Remove id from table
5. Regenerate "**Othertable**"
6. Add these lines to "**Othertable**":

   ```
   //imitate id
   public $id; 

   //rediclare init
   public function init() {
       parent::init();
       $this->id= $this->sometable_id; 
   }

   // Rediclare primary key. For this condition sometable_id 
   // have chosen as primary
   // key. We can change it
   public static function primaryKey() {
       return ['sometable_id'];
   }
   ```
7. Remove ***id*** from **OthertableSearch** model
8. Change findModel($id) method on **OthertableController** as:

```
 protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Othertable::find()->where(['sometable_id'=>$id])->one()) !== null) {
            $model->id=$model->sometable_id;
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
```

**Attentions**

In this example I used sometable_id of the "**othertable**" assuming that there is only one record on the table with this sometable_id value (a.g. unique), otherwise every time you can get first record and change/delete that instead needed one. It can be changed to other unique variable(s) of the table. If you want use other variable, you should  change on model and on findModel() method of the controller.

Comment: Please improve your answer with methods to escape errors on generated files